# 404 Error after uploading laravel 5.2 project to the shared host

Tags: .htaccess, laravel-5, shared-hosting

We have recently uploaded a laravel 5.2 project to the server, the problem is it shows the first page which is a login page however none of other pages works and returns a 404 error.
Here is the .htaccess:

```html
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On
    
    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ public/$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

I would be happy if anyone can help me out with this.

Answer (score 0):

```
# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ public/$1 [L,R=301]
```

In this lines. Is your apache set to directory /path/to/project **/public**.
If that is the case then all requests are hitting the public folder. This means you should place your .htaccess file inside /public folder.

Then your RewriteRule should go as:

```
# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

Since you are already in the public folder.